# Strange character in downvote notification for one of my questions

Tags: bug, notifications, notification-bar, encoding

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22524789) a month ago on stackoverflow.com. Today, when I logged in to SO, the notification area showed me a strange character:

> [image]

It looks like a downvote, but downvotes usually appear as `-2`, not ...*that*. Could someone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess that is a encoding bug. I'm sure that should be a simple "-2" which indicates a normal downvote.

Here is a screenshot where you can see that you got a downvote:
[image: Downvote]

Comment: I checked my reputation too on clicking reputation tab, there it is. You're right.

Answer (score 8):

For some reason the achievements drop down is using ["en dash"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) (–) unicode character instead of the ordinary "-" character to mark negative reputation.

Your browser simply does not support the "en dash", as you'll most likely see in [its test page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/browsertest.htm).

Bug or feature? Only the team can answer that, but the above is the reason for what you see.

Comment: I can see "-" not that strange one in the test page you shared :)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto weird, but still something on your end and likely related to  using that character.

Comment: Ah! That can be possible!

Comment: That's definitely a bug.  It *should* be using a [minus sign (U+2212)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm).